# Applying hover pseudo class only to letters of a link?

Tags: html, css, hover, anchor, pseudo-element

I just want the letters of the link to change color when user hovers on the link with their mouse.

Is this done by just using the a (for anchor) selector when selecting the element in css?

I don't want anything but the letters changing color.

Comment: did u wrote any code? please post your code. We cant write from the scratch.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Perhaps you could explain further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/sa16pm5g/

```
<a href="#"> I'm your link </a>

a:hover {
color: black;
```

}

Insufficient information to give any other answer.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.